# Linearly independence and nullity of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Just been tackling this question but im not sure how to finish the last part..

Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear map where $dim(V)=n$, and suppose that $T^n=0$ and there exists a vector $v \in V$ with $T^{n-1}(v) \neq 0_v$. Prove that the  vectors $v,T(v),T^2(v),...,T^{n-1}(v)$ are linearly independent and that the nullity of $T$ is 1.

So for linear independence i had

$\alpha_0v + \alpha_1T(v) + ... + \alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}(v) = 0$ $(*)$

So if we apply $T^{n-1}$ to $(*)$ then we get

$T^{n-1}(\alpha_0v) + T^{n-1}(\alpha_1T(v)) + ... + T^{n-1}(\alpha_{n-1}T^{n-1}(v)) = \alpha_0T^{n-1}(v)=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_0 = 0$ and then we can say that if we repeat the process etc all $\alpha_i (0 \leq i \leq n )$ are equal to 0, hence the vectors must be linearly independent.

For the second part, i.e. showing that the nullity 1, i know that $ n = rank(T) + null(T)$. And i have a set of linearly independent vectors, so all i would have to do is show that those vectors span the space then i can deduce the rank is n-1?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know that $T(v), T^2(v), T^3(v),...,T^{n-1}(v)$ are linearly independent vectors in the range of $T$, so the rank of $T$ is at least $n-1$. But also $T^{n-1}(v)$ is a nonzero vector in the kernel of $T$, so the nullity of $T$ is at least $1$. Then by rank nullity you are done.